Why can't I use Array.from to create an Array from a Map's keys or values?
From the docs I've been reading, the following ought to create an Array from the keys of a Map:


var m = new Map();
m.set("a", 1);
m.set("b", 2);

var arr1 = Array.from(m.keys());
var arr2 = Array.from(m.values());

console.log(arr1.length);
console.log(arr2.length);



I'd expect that to print 2 for both arrays, but in reality both arrays are empty and it prints 0. What gives?
Edit: This issue seems to occur on a specific webpage when I execute the above code in the Javascript console. If I execute it on other pages it works as expected.
Edit 2: Upon further investigation, it appears that the page in question is including prototype.js v1.6.1 which is somehow causing Array.from to break.

For me, your code does indeed print 2 for both arrays.  So can you please provide a reproducible example?  Be aware that a webpage may modify Array.from or any other function.

This issue is due to a conflict with the prototype.js library. (As @Bri Bri mentioned.)
prototype.js is overriding or interfering with the native Array.from method, and because of that it malfunctions. This can result in Array.from not working as expected and not delivering the correct result, leading to empty arrays when trying to convert the keys and values of the Map object.
To work around this issue, use the Array Spread operator. 1


var m = new Map();
m.set("a", 1);
m.set("b", 2);

var arr1 = [...m.keys()];
var arr2 = [...m.values()];

console.log("Keys :"+JSON.stringify(arr1.length)); // 2
console.log("Values :"+JSON.stringify(arr2.length)); // 2




Your first example is a valid workaround. Your second example however doesn't make sense. For one, using slice does not actually work: [].slice consistently returns an empty array when passed a Map Iterator, regardless of whether prototype.js is included. Second, with that typeof Array.from === 'function' test, it's not even using slice but rather will always use Array.from, and therefore will suffer from the same issue when prototype.js is included!

Yeah use first example as answer then. Appreciate marking it as correct answer and giving an upvote :-)

This appears to be caused by a known bug in prototype.js. See this GitHub issue "Native Array.from is overwritten by $A which is not able to handle all cases used by the native function #338".
An excerpt from the issue:

From the definition of these two functions:
The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.
However, the $A function only accepts an array-like collection (anything with numeric indices).
So $A is not able to handle other iterable objects without numeric indices such as MapIterator.
When $A try to create a new array by reading the iterable.length which does exist in some native iterable objects such as MapIterator, the result will be an array with length 0 returned back.

